# mysql binary keyword issue with special characters

Tags: mysql, php

Password in database:- !|%$&./()=?ì^

If I use below query:-

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE Password='!|%$&./()=?ì^' AND Status='1'
```

This works fine.

But I am checking for case sensitive passwords with below query:-

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE BINARY Password='!|%$&./()=?ì^' AND Status='1'
```

This does not provide any data. On removing ì, this works.

Password field collation: latin1_swedish_ci

Note:- I can not change collation because there are too much data in database.

Any suggestion will be appreciable.

Comment: Error:- COLLATION 'latin1_general_cs' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'

Comment: If so then alter table, convert your column charset to UTF8MB4 and set correct case-sensitive collation to it.

Comment: If you are looking into MySQL's passwords, they don't work that way.  If `user` is your table, then please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: What client is performing the `SELECT`?  We need to know because of the likelihood that it is interpreting some of that punctuation in special ways.